# Can I have a non-static data member in a static class?

Tags: c#, static, static-methods, static-members

I want to know if in a static class, all the methods and data member should be static or can I find a non static members?

Comment: No. You can't. It's the purpose main of a static class. Why do you need of it? What are you planning? maybe by showing a bit of your scenery you can get a more right desginer-implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All members are static. Of course they are, because if you can't instantiate an object from that class, why would there be any non-static members?

Answer (score 7):

[First link back](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) from [Google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=static%20class%20c#)

> The main features of a static class are:
>
> - They only contain static members.

Answer (score 2):

You can have a non-static class with both static and non-static methods but a static class can only have static methods.